# Запятая перед тире при быстрой смене действий

Tags: запятые, тире

Какой вариант верен?

1. Время ускорилось, вернулось к нормальному ритму, — и в сердце вдруг что-то больно кольнуло.
2. Время ускорилось, вернулось к нормальному ритму — и в сердце вдруг что-то больно кольнуло.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. По правилам  здесь ставится тире:  ***Время ускорилось, вернулось к нормальному ритму — и в сердце вдруг что-то больно кольнуло.***

Тире в сложносочиненном предложении (ССП)  является **неосновным знаком**, оно заменяет запятую и ставится при определенных условиях. В данном случае подходит пункт 1 правил Розенталя  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135

Если во второй части ССП содержится **неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление,** то между частями перед сочинительным союзом вместо запятой ставится тире:  Тут раздался лёгкий свист — и Дубровский умолк (П.); Все вскочили, схватились за ружья — и пошла потеха (Л.); Но вот опять хлынули играющие лучи — и весело и величаво поднимается могучее светило (Т.); Вавила бросил что-то в костёр, притоптал — и тотчас же стало очень темно (Ч.).

2. Что можно сказать **о едином знаке «запятая и тире»?** Он обычно ставится в сложноподчиненных и бессоюзных предложениях, и там его употребление также регламентируется. С точки зрения интонации,  единый знак обозначает **значительно удлиненную паузу** (по длительности паузы он сравним с двоеточием). Использование его в ССП, вероятно, следует считать **авторским знаком.**

В данном случае надо знать контекст, чтобы **обосновать авторский знак.** Как я думаю, причиной его постановки может быть именно **длительная пауза** (как говорят в театре, актер  должен уметь держать паузу). Если это соответствует **художественной задаче,** то использование единого знака здесь допустимо: ***Время ускорилось, вернулось к нормальному ритму, — и в сердце вдруг что-то больно кольнуло.***